# Cuando utilizar ENUM y cuando crear una nueva tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, join, enum

Supongamos que quiero guardar el genero de una persona, sabiendo que estos valores serán limitados para mi aplicación y no mutarán en el tiempo con tanta frecuencia (por no decir nula)... 
Seria mejor aplicar el genero como un atributo ENUM o crear una nueva tabla para almacenarlos?

En temas de rendimiento, considerando que el genero deberé traerlo en muchas ocasiones ¿Que es más eficiente? ¿Enum o un join con otra tabla?

¿Hasta cuantos valores es aceptable tener en un campo ENUM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues, teniendo en cuenta que el tipo `ENUM` no funciona como una `FK` y que debes crear un `TRIGGER` para que impida registrar datos en blanco, yo me decantaría por una clave ajena `FK` a la tabla que comentas, de forma que me permita añadir (*) más posibilidades en el futuro sin hacer un `ALTER TABLE`.

Puedes comprobar lo que te comento con este código:

```
CREATE TABLE generos(
  id_genero int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  genero enum('M','V') NOT NULL 
  );
INSERT INTO generos (genero) VALUES
  ('M'),
  ('V'),
  ('F'),
  ('N');
```

Verás que, cuando insertas un valor inválido, mete un dato en blanco. Un `FK` es más restrictivo y te impide insertar el registro.

(*) Con respecto a la inmutabilidad del género, igual la comunidad LGTBIQ+ no lo tiene tan claro... :)